# What won't image go inside div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an image inside a div of the same dimension but for some reason the image keeps appearing to right of the div even though it's inside the div in my html:

```
<div>
  <img width="16" height="16"></img>
</div>
```

I created a JSfiddle that shows what's going on: https://jsfiddle.net/5q0s3y1j/

Can anybody help me understand how to put the image inside the div?

Comment: the absolute keyword in the image is causing this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `left: 20px;` in your `.userFlair` css. It's telling the image to shift 20 pixels left from the start of the container, which is larger than the container itself.

Changing this to `left: 0;` or omitting it completely will put the image in the div.

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q0s3y1j/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the left: 20px on your image class.

```
.userFlair {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    // left: 20px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5q0s3y1j/2/

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to position your img separately. You can simplify your code to just this css.

```css
.lobbyFlair {
  border: 1px solid red;
 height: 16px;
 width: 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="lobbyFlair">
  <img class="userFlair" width="16" height="16" src='http://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_2dde66f8a62c_16.png'/>
</div>
```